# Core Data: Save failing on mandatory field, but value should be set!

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have an abstract entity called `Block` which contains two attributes: `column` and `order` (which are not optional), and one relationship, `thing`, where it is the detail of a 1->M. I have another entity, `Whatever`, that has `Block` as its parent, and adds one attribute, `someNumber`.

My code looks like this:

```
Whatever *block = (Whatever *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Whatever" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
block.order = 0;
block.column = 0;
block.thing = self.thing;
```

When I try to save, I get this error:

```
Failed to save to data store: Operation could not be completed. (Cocoa error 1560.)
DetailedError: {
  NSLocalizedDescription = "Operation could not be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)";
  NSValidationErrorKey = column;
  NSValidationErrorObject = <Whatever: 0x5124890> (entity: someWhatever; id: 0x511b4e0 <x-coredata:///Whatever/t718B63A4-927B-4D88-A9E6-7F61CF9621675> ; 
  data: {
    column = nil;
    thing = 0x54367a0 <x-coredata://E6648244-E5FC-4202-B5F9-C7A91BACF8DA/Thing/p2>;
    order = nil;
    someNumber = 0;
  });
```

I don't understand why it says that `column` and `order` are `nil`, as I've just set them the line before, so this shouldn't be a problem.

I've tried using the `[block setColumn:0]` style as well, without success.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting them to nil since nil is just a null or zero pointer value.

Core Data properties must be set to objects (as opposed to primitive types).

Integers and floating point numbers are NSNumber objects.

I like to use the numberWith* convenience constructors.

For example:

```
block.order = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];
block.column = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting my objective-c-legs, as it were. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on gerry3's answer, a great way to ease coding with Core Data is to use Rentzsch's [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator). It would allow you to do:

```
block.orderValue = 0;
block.columnValue = 0;
```